# extracting a string out of another url or string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to extract the store/brand names out of the url or some title string.

so the url could be something like

```
"http://www.store1.com/brand1-Transform-Ultra-Prepaid-/"

and title could be " brand1 Transform Ultra Prepaid Phone "
```

I will keep the possible store names in an array like

```
var store_array  = ['store1', 'brand1', 'brand2']
```

lets say if i search the above url or title, i should get the store1 and brand1 as a result.

how to do this in jquery, am beginner, please explain me in detail.

my initial idea is that i should below, but not sure. please help.

```
$.each( store_array, function(index, value) {
```

//what to do here
});

Comment: I couldn't understand what is it that you want.

Comment: edited it, wrote the possible outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
var url = 'http://www.store1.com/brand1-Transform-Ultra-Prepaid-/',
    path = url.split('/');

var store_array = path[path.length-2].split('-');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jcGsp/

This all depends on how dynamic you want it to be, another options would be a regexp:

```
var url = 'http://www.store1.com/brand1-Transform-Ultra-Prepaid-/';

var store_array = url.replace(/http:\/\/www.store1.com\/([^\/]+)\//,'$1').split('-');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fSpr3/

Comment: sorry could not understand how i will search brand names in this.
also, store name is easy to find using window.location.host. am more concerned about searching brand names

Comment: The `store_array` in my answer holds an array of all the brands included in the URL path, is that not what you asked?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the split function:
let's say the url is:

```
url=window.location.href;
url.split('http://www.store1.com/');
title=url[1];
```

if the word needed from "brand1-Transform-Ultra-Prepaid-" is "brand1" then split this again with:

```
title.split('-');
fixed_title=title[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define a function to do the matching, and run it on the strings I am interested in

```
function findMatches( str ){
   return store_array.filter( function( el ){
    return new RegExp( "\b"+el+"\b", "i" ).test( str );
   });
}

var results1 = findMatches( 'http://www.store1.com/' );
var results2 = findMatches( " brand1 Transform Ultra Prepaid Phone " );
//etc
```

The \b ensures 'store1' etc are complete words (so, 'store1' wouldn't match 'megastore1') and the /i makes it case insensitive.

array.filter runs a function on every member of an array and returns a copy of the array with only those members for whose the function returns true. Note that array.filter is IE9 and above (you didn't specify the platform), for other browsers there is anice polyfill here https://gist.github.com/1031656

The findMatches function goes through all the strings in the list, turns them into regular expressions, and checks whether it is found in the string. If you have a lot of test string, it may be more efficient to run indexof

```
function findMatches( str ){
   return store_array.filter( function( el ){
    return ( "-1" !== str.indexOf( el ) );
   });
}
```

Either will work. Note that this is not using jQuery, just plain JS (albeit ECMA5)

Comment: Thanks, you solution is somewhat near to desired results. however i have cleaned the url and title before running any search on them. for example i do  URL.toLowerCase().replace(this.ft9_alpha_num_rgx, ' ') and the find the indexOf using lowercase.